# Component Not Rendering (ReactJS/MaterialUI)

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In my div, I have a function which renders components based on what is present in an object. However, even though `cat.comp` returns the actual functional component, it does not get rendered.

This is my render function:

```
{cardsInGrid.map((card) => {
            sideBarCategories.map((cat) => {
              if (card.id === cat.id) {
                const Component = cat.comp;
                return <Component key={card.id} />;
              }
            });
          })}
```

Comment: Return the inner map or remove the bracket's from its parent arrow function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nothing is being returned from the first `map`. You need to `return` the array of elements:

```js
          {cardsInGrid.map((card) => {
            return sideBarCategories.map((cat) => {
              if (card.id === cat.id) {
                const Component = cat.comp;
                return <Component key={card.id} />;
              }
            });
          })}
```

However, this is going to result in a two-dimensional array so you'll need to flatten that. One approach would be to move this out of the component tree and create a one-dimensional array. For example, something along the lines of:

```
const elements = [];

cardsInGrid.forEach(card => {
  sideBarCategories.forEach(cat => {
    const Component = cat.comp;
    elements.push(<Component key={card.id + cat.id} />);
  });
});

return <>{elements}</>;
```

After further discussion, it sounds like you only ever have one component and you want to find that specific category and render it. In that case, I would suggest using `find` (or equivalent logic). For example:

```js
{cardsInGrid.map(card => {
  const Component = sideBarCategories.find(cat => cat.id === card.id).comp;
  return <Component key={card.id} />;
})}
```

Comment: I didn't look so detailed to the code, so good catch :) I don't know what OP wants but I'm upvoting your answer.

Comment: @skovy I have an map with an id and the corresponding component and what I am trying to do is get the ids listed in the `cardsInGrid` array and find the corresponding component which is listed with that same id in `sideBarCategories`. What would be the most efficient way of doing that?

Comment: @NathanealVarghese I updated the answer, I would suggest using `find`. Is this the problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: @skovy That works flawlessly! Thank you so much, I learned about the .find function!

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the `return` in your first `map` method. You should add it:

```
{
  cardsInGrid.map((card) => {
    return sideBarCategories.map((cat) => {
      if (card.id === cat.id) {
        const Component = cat.comp;
        return <Component key={card.id} />;
      }
    });
  });
}
```

or you can use implicit return:

```
{
  cardsInGrid.map((card) =>
    sideBarCategories.map((cat) => {
      if (card.id === cat.id) {
        const Component = cat.comp;
        return <Component key={card.id} />;
      }
    })
  );
}
```

Comment: Thank you for that. The return in front of it worked. Do you have any way of simplifying the function itself?

Comment: Well, it seems pretty straightforward to me :) If the result is what you want then go ahead. Also, you can check @skovy's answer.